# JavaScript: Analytics Track Event won't fire

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've put the function into form validation part, so that only when form is valid, the beacon would be sent. I am sure I am missing something. See code below.

```
function checkForm() {
    var error = "";
    if($("#first_name").val()=="") { error+="- Enter your first name.\n";};
    if(error=="") {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Form','Submit','Newsletter']);
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please correct these form errors before you submit the form:\n\n"+error)
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks everyone for their help! Tested  this one, and 100ms doesn't seem to be enough.

Now I am thinking to do this a little more clever way. It would make sense to submit it, once all required fields have text in it, but it should be clever enough to submit more than once and submit only when data is valid!

Comment: whats your question? please share the error you are getting.

Comment: I don't get a any error. The event won't appear in dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give a delay (may be about 100 miliseconds or less) using setTimeout() or setInterval() and let the GA datato be submited. Worked for me.

```
function gaSubmit(param){
_gaq.push(param);
}

function checkForm() {
    var error = "";
    if($("#first_name").val()=="") { error+="- Enter your first name.\n";};
    if(error=="") {
        setTimeout(gaSubmit(['_trackEvent','Form','Submit','Newsletter']),100);
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please correct these form errors before you submit the form:\n\n"+error)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure if it's not fires? Probably there is some delay in analytics data refresh. If you develop your app on localhost, then you should set _setDomainName property to 'none'

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Your-account-id']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
```

@see:[GA Event Tracking from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215745/ga-event-tracking-from-localhost)

Comment: Hi, executing the same from console does register. I was reading somewhere about the delays (not dashboard delays) and some people opting for async submit.