# how can I use google tag manager events via localhost?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using google tag manager events on my site

In firebug I can see that my events are firing!

```
GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.9&utms=16&utmn=705393378&utmhn=localhost&utmt=event&utme=5(Brand%20menu*click%20on%20brand*HID%20do%20Brasil)&etc
Host: www.google-analytics.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Referer: http://localhost/en/local/
```

But I cannot see any real time events in my google analytics panel

Is it possible to use gtm via localhost at all?

this is an extract of my js code for the gtm events:

```
          jQuery('.brand-list-tooltip li a').click(function () {
            var targetName = jQuery(this).text();
            var brandName = jQuery(this).parents('.show-tip').find('a').first().text();
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Brand menu', 'click on brand country', brandName]);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Brand menu', 'click on brand country', targetName]);
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GA Event Tracking from localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215745/ga-event-tracking-from-localhost)

Comment: Tag Manager does not seem to have anything to do with it (by the look of it you are confusing tag manager events which trigger a tag and Google Analytics events which record data).

Comment: I updated my question with a code snippet. I'm sending an event via gtm to be able to track the click in google > real time > events

Comment: Yes. That means GTM works fine, otherwise you could not see the events firing at all. These are Analytics Events, not GTM events. Read the anwser in the linked question which adresses Google Analytics on localhost.

Comment: FYI, I had to revert to the old implementation of GA events from GTM due to a clash between those two on my site. so this question is not relevant anymore.